# Puppet exec/wget

Tags: puppet, wget

I am trying to download a file from remote location into a directory in puppet.

.pp file

```
class test::test {

  exec { 'wget http://10.0.0.1/test/test.txt':
    cwd     => '/opt/check',
    path    => ['/usr/bin', '/usr/sbin',],
  }
}
```

I also tried with wget module in puppet :

```
class test::test {

  include ::wget

  wget::fetch { 'http://10.0.0.1/test/test.txt':
    destination => '/tmp/',
    timeout     => 0,
    verbose     => false,
  }
}
```

I am not getting the file downloaded, is there something i am doing wrong or is there a better way?
Please let me know.

Comment: I don't see any obvious error in the code presented.  Have you actually assigned class `test::test` to the node you're trying to configure?  If so, then it would be wise to gather more information by running the agent with `--debug` logging enabled to get more information about what's failing.  It might also help to run the same command manually (and as the same user the agent runs as, probably `root`) to check whether the command itself is the problem.

Comment: The `file` resource can also retrieve remote files with `http` URIs, and would probably be easier as a well-supported native resource.

Answer (score 1):

Run `which wget` on your node to ensure you are including the right path, on my centos machine it's /bin/wget.
I often (and it's probably a bad habit) include the full path in the comand so I'd put `/bin/wget http://10.0.0.1/test/test.txt`
Have you tried running that command on the machine manualy?
Check this link out https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/type.html#exec

```
exec { 'get-test.txt':
  cwd     => '/opt/check',
  command => '/bin/wget http://10.0.0.1/test/test.txt',
  path    => ['/usr/bin', '/usr/sbin',],
  creates => '/opt/check/test.txt',
}
```

The "creates" stops running the exec if the file exists, you want to do that or every time puppet runs (default every 30 minutes) it'll run that command again.

I just ran a test on my machine, I created a file `test.pp` and put this in it;

```
exec { 'get-google':
  cwd     => '/tmp',
  command => '/bin/wget http://www.google.com',
  path    => ['/usr/bin', '/usr/sbin',],
  creates => '/tmp/index.html',
}
```

Then ran `puppet apply test.pp`and it worked, if you want to test small blocks of code that's a handy way of doing it.

Also, does the `/opt/check` directory exist?